# Is there a way to add font with subset true to Acroform PDField

Tags: java, pdfbox, acrofields

I have a pdf with PDTextField, on setting value(Ayşe) with font

```
PDFont font  = PDType0Font.load(document,new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/fonts/ArialUnicodeMSBold.ttf"), true);
```

prints gibberish text.

Although with subset as false it works , but **increases the file size from 122kb to ~6 MB.**

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: There are smaller fonts, like liberation-sans.

Comment: Thank you @TilmanHausherr for your suggestion. Will switch to liberation-sans